# How to sum 1:15 this type of values in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to sum 1:15 this type of values in SQL server

I try this query:

```
select sum((SELECT REPLACE(
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), TotalTime, 108),
           ':',
           '.'
          ) where Associate='4587')
          )
from Tracking
where Associate='4587'
```

error showing:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 45
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: is this column in `Time` format? and are you trying to sum the time?

Comment: column datatype is varchar

Comment: yes i want sum the time

Comment: @fa06 I tried this also            SELECT 
    SUM(TotalTime) ,
( convert( int, (select cast(datepart(hour, TotalTime) + datepart(minute, TotalTime ) / 60.00 as decimal(5, 2) ) from Tracking where Associate='2614')) )
from Tracking where Associate='2614'

Comment: That inner `where Associate='4587'` is out of place. Why is it there?

Comment: Also, if `1:15` stands for 1 hour and 15 minutes (or 1 minute and 15 seconds), replacing `:` with `.` will give you the wrong results.

Comment: @zohzr peled  I want  specific Associate time 4587  is id of Associate

Comment: @ZoharPeled  stands for 1 hour and 15 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how you can sum a time column. 
It returns a Days, Time and a datetime. Time will be relevant as long as the sum is less than 24 hours otherwise it should be combined with Days. The datetime will include the day part as days after 1900-01-01.

The query require valid data with data format hh:mi or h:mi:

```
DECLARE @ table(col int, TotalTime time)

INSERT @ values(1,'1:15'),(1,'0:30'),(1,'0:05'),(1,'23:30'),(2,'1:15'),(2,'1:30')
SELECT
  col,
  datediff(d, 0, cast(sum(cast(cast(totaltime as datetime) as float)) as datetime)) Days,
  cast(cast(sum(cast(cast(totaltime as datetime) as float)) as datetime) as time(0)) Time,
  cast(sum(cast(cast(totaltime as datetime) as float)) as smalldatetime) DT
FROM 
  @
GROUP BY col
```

Result:

```
col Days  Time     DT
1   1     01:20:00 1900-01-02 01:20:00
2   0     02:45:00 1900-01-01 02:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using conditional aggregation

```
select sum(case when Associate='2614' then REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), TotalTime, 108), ':', '.' ) end) 
from Tracking where Associate='4587'
```

Comment: your code error:-Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: @ganesh, what is your totaltime column data type

Comment: column data type is varchar

Comment: what is your expected output ? @ganesh

Comment: if there two values like 1:15 and 00:45 I want 2:00

Comment: I tried this also SELECT 
    SUM(TotalTime) ,
( convert( int, (select cast(datepart(hour, TotalTime) + datepart(minute, TotalTime ) / 60.00 as decimal(5, 2) ) from Tracking where Associate='2614')) )
from Tracking where Associate='2614'

Comment: @ganesh, is your above query gives your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have chosen the wrong data type to store this value, and this can lead to to a lot of problems, starting with ill-formatted values (What's stopping you from having a value like `'1:86'`, or even worst - `'dyjst'` in that column?), through having to perform needlessly complicated queries to get some of the results (just like this one), ambiguous values such as `13:2` - Is that 20 minutes or just 2?, and there are a bunch of other problems I didn't write because I think you should get the picture by now.

Surly the best way to solve this issue is to change the way you store the data. If this data represents an hour in a day, you should be using the `Time` data type. If it stores a duration that might be larger than 24 hours, you might want to simply calculate the number of minutes and store that in an int.

However, assuming that for some reason (and yes, some of them might be valid reasons) you can't change the way you store this data - you will need to write a query that will translate this data for you to the number of minutes it represents (This would also be the case if you where to store it in the `Time` data type - you can't do `SUM` on `Time` values), and then sum that value. If you want to display it back as the same format (`[h]h:mm`), you will need to translate the value from the `sum` back to this format.

I've put together a small demo that will show you one way to translate a string formatted as `hh:mm` to number of minutes and back - Once you get the number of minutes as an int, using `sum` is easy. **Note**: I didn't add any validation for the content of the strings!

So first, create and populate sample table (**Please**, save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @Tracking AS TABLE
(
    TotalTime varchar(10),
    Associate varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO @Tracking (TotalTime, Associate) VALUES
('1:15', '4587'),
('1:05', '4588'),
('22:33', '4589'),
('73:50', '4590'),
('120:85', '4591'); -- Note: this will translate back as 121:25
```

Then, create a common table expression to translate the value in the TotalTime column to the number of minutes it represents:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Associate, 
            TotalTime As TotalTime,
            CAST(LEFT(TotalTime, CHARINDEX(':', TotalTime) - 1) AS Int) * 60 +
            CAST(RIGHT(TotalTime, LEN(TotalTime) - CHARINDEX(':', TotalTime)) As int)
            As NumberOfMinutes
    FROM @Tracking
)
```

And a select statement to translate it back to a time string:

```
SELECT  Associate, TotalTime, NumberOfMinutes,
        CAST((NumberOfMinutes - (NumberOfMinutes % 60)) / 60 As varchar(3)) + ':' +
        RIGHT('00' + CAST(NumberOfMinutes % 60 As varchar(2)), 2) As TimeString
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
Associate   TotalTime   NumberOfMinutes     TimeString
4587        1:15        75                  1:15
4588        1:05        65                  1:05
4589        22:33       1353                22:33
4590        73:50       4430                73:50
4591        120:85      7285                121:25
```